# .NET Core DI: Configuration of libraries using libraries

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, configuration, .net-core, class-library

I am planning to convert an assorted toolbox project into various NuGet packages. The idea is to use the `services.AddMvc()`-esque style of dependency injection (I am not sure what it's called). Let's call it the **ConfigureServices pattern**.

In short, the idea is to enable to use of libraries as follows:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddSomeLibrary(/* potential configuration here */);
    // ...
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application)
{
    // ...
    application.UseSomeLibrary(); // If necessary
    // ...
}
```

> **Question 1:** Is there a preferred way to get something like a connection string into the `AddSomeLibrary()` extension method?

---

An additional challenge arises when OuterLibrary depends on InnerLibrary, which, in turn, requires some configuration - let's say a connection string.

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // AddOuterLibrary's implementation will call AddInnerLibrary(...)
    // Are we going to ask for InnerLibrary's configuration input here?
    services.AddOuterLibrary(...);
}
```

> **Question 2:** How should `AddOuterLibrary()` get the configuration input it needs to call `AddInnerLibrary()`?

Particularly, I imagine that certain configuration options might look very obscure without knowledge of which sublibrary is being configured by them.

Perhaps an answer could use the example of an outer library depending on a logging library. The logging library would need a concrete type of logger to use (one that logs to ElasticSearch, one that logs to MySql, ...) and a connection string (which only makes sense for its particular concrete type of logger).

---

And then there is the possibility that InnerLibrary is *also* used directly by our application, and perhaps by a third library as well.

> **Question 3:** When a library adds another library, should it use the main service collection, i.e. use the same container instance as the rest of the application, or should it use its own, separate container instance?

I suppose that if we use the main container then the following is true:

- We keep the inversion of control, giving the composition root control over even the dependencies of libraries.
- It becomes hard to make an included library use (for example) another logging endpoint than our application's own logic. (Silly example, but there may be more relevant ones.)
- It could become obscure that we are configuring the logging, which may affect the entire application, even though it *looks* like we are merely configuring one library.

Comment: take a look how they do it with [Identity](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) for example

Comment: @vasily.sib I see that Identity uses fluent syntax to further configure the component, e.g. `.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()`. What happens if you `AddIdentity()` without calling those fluent methods? Looks very easy to "forget" - how do you know that it expects you to call fluent methods, and which?

Comment: If I `AddIdentity(..)` without `AddEntityFrameworkStores(..)` it will throw an exception telling me that I forget to add stores

Comment: @vasily.sib Good to know! At what point does it throw this exception? I presume as soon as you try to actually use (or `Use...()`) anything from it?

Comment: As far as I know - no. `AddIdentity(..)` just add base Identity classes in DI (like `services.TryAddScoped<UserManager<TUser>>();`). This classes depend on stores implementations (which are added by `AddEntityFrameworkStores(..)`)

Comment: I'm trying to understand (in order to mimic) at which point the class has the chance to confirm that it has been correctly configured. From your last comment, do I understand that `AddEntityFrameworkStores(...)` simply registers certain components that Identity requires in its constructors? So that it would throw at construction time? But that would lead to vague errors: "Unable to resolve SomeType" instead of "You forgot to add stores".

Comment: There should be _"Unable to resolve SomeType"_ kind of exception, but it is not vague. When I get this exception, I went to my `Startup.cs` to check where I register that type within `ConfigureServices`. The easiest way to check is to try:)